# Vue 3 Checkbox not checking and unchecking on click

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I am using simple checkbox and using primevue library.

My checkbox is visible but i don't know how can i make it working.

My Code looks like this.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Checkbox />
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Checkbox from "primevue/checkbox"
import { defineComponent } from "vue"
export default defineComponent({
  name: "FormElement",

  components: { Checkbox },

  methods: {},
  computed: {},
})
</script>
```

Usage:

```
<template>
  <div class="test">
    <FormElement />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue"
import FormElement from "@/components/FormElement/FormElement.vue"

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    FormElement,
  },

})
</script>
```

Vue Dev Console, Child Component:

[image: Vue dev console]

Vue Dev Console, Parent component:

[image: Vue dev console]

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to make it do, [here is an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-grass-mxcpj?file=/src/App.vue) where checking it adds a value to an array. You can use v-model on the element.

Comment: But i posted my whole code. Why is this not working?
I don't wanna go with array.

Comment: The array is just an example. You need to add state for the checkbox, e.g. using v-model https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox

Comment: The docs for the checkbox have multiple examples https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/checkbox

Comment: You have posted vue 2 link. I am working with vue 3

Comment: I'm pretty sure the principal is the same but whatever, here you go https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#checkbox

Answer (score 0):

To make the button clickable, make sure to add the `v-model` binding.

The checkbox will be unusable until you add the `v-model` binding to hold the state of the button somewhere. In the full PrimeVue example, this is done using a simple setup script which is run for every button:

```js
<template>
    <div class="card flex justify-content-center">
        <Checkbox v-model="checked" :binary="true" />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { ref } from "vue";
    const checked = ref(false);
</script>
```

[Simple button example](https://primevue.org/checkbox/#basic) (Make sure to click "Toggle Full Code" in the snippet.)